# How can I use data in a string to update a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following data array:

```
var ans = 
[
 {"text":"x","response":false},
 {"text":"y","response":false},
 {"text":"z","response":true}
];

var correct = "010"; // I need to add this to the array ans
```

Can anyone suggest how I could use use the data in the correct variable to add to the array so as to make:

```
var ans = 
[
 {"text":"x","response":false,"correct":false},
 {"text":"y","response":false,"correct":true},
 {"text":"z","response":true,"correct":false}
];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i< ans.length; i++) {
    ans[i].correct = correct.charAt(i) == "1";
}
```

Comment: I see you are setting the value to "1" will this be the same as setting to true?

Comment: I'm not setting it to 1. I'm setting it to a result of (correct.charAt(i) == "1") comparison which is a boolean value: true or false

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
    ans[i]["correct"] = correct[i] === "1";
}
```

Comment: I see you are setting the value to "1" will this be the same as setting to true?

Comment: We are not setting the value to "1", we are setting the value to the result of comparison (correct[i] === "1"), which can be either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You an also do it like this(using a for-in loop).

Reference: [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

```
for(key in ans){
    ans[key].correct = correct.charAt(key) == "1";
}
```

Comment: I see you are setting the value to "1" will this be the same as setting to true?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ans = 
    [
     {"text":"x","response":false},
     {"text":"y","response":false},
     {"text":"z","response":true}
    ];

var correct = "010";

var sep = correct.split("");

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sep.length; i++) {
     if (sep[i] == 0) {
       arr.push("false");
      } else {
       arr.push("true");
     }
   }

  var len = ans.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        ans[i].correct = arr[i];
    }
```